# How can I Bind a Custom Table Header to the Data correctly in Quasar / Vue

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to override the standard headings in a quasar table .  Mainly because I need a stacked header ( 2 rows with colspans / rowspans ) . I can get it looking right , but I can't get it behaving like a proper table header - mainly the fact that it won't sort. I have tried several ways to declaratively bind it.

```
<q-table
    :data="data"
    :columns="columns"
    row-key="name" class="col-12">
    <template v-slot:header="props">
      <q-tr :props="props">
          <q-th rowspan="2" >Sku</q-th>
          <q-th rowspan="2">Name</q-th>
          <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Sales</q-th>
          <q-th rowspan="2" style="text-align:center">Order</q-th>
          <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Before Order</q-th>
          <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">After Order</q-th>
          <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Order</q-th>
       </q-tr>
       <q-tr :props="props">
          <q-th>Qty</q-th>
          <q-th>Count</q-th>
          <q-th>Daily</q-th>
          <q-th>Stock</q-th>
          <q-th>Days</q-th>
          <q-th>Date</q-th>
          <q-th>Stock</q-th>
          <q-th>Days</q-th>
          <q-th>Date</q-th>
          <q-th>Price</q-th>
          <q-th>Discount</q-th>
          <q-th>Total</q-th>
       </q-tr>
  </template>
</q-table>
```

Comment: Can you please share the array of objects , what you stored in "data", that would really help to solve this issue

Comment: Also please share the sample table, how to want to display..

Comment: @chans here is a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-app-2im4s

Comment: You code is in which component

Comment: In got the component code, I'll share you the updated code in sandbox

Comment: Thanks @chans - the actual page is https://2im4s.sse.codesandbox.io/purchase-orders

Comment: Thanks for the update, check  the below answer , it works as expected..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refactored the code and added key and separate props to pass to each headers along the with the key 'name', now it is working as expected

Working code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-app-edivz

Live page URL: https://edivz.sse.codesandbox.io/purchase-orders

```
<q-table
        :data="data"
        :columns="columns"
        row-key="name" class="col-12">
        <template v-slot:header="props">
          <q-tr>
              <q-th :props="props" key="sku" rowspan="2" >Sku</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="name" rowspan="2">Name</q-th>
              <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Sales</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="Qty" rowspan="2" style="text-align:center">Order</q-th>
              <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Before Order</q-th>
              <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">After Order</q-th>
              <q-th colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Order</q-th>
           </q-tr>
           <q-tr>
              <q-th :props="props" key="SalesQty">Qty</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="SalesCount">Count</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="DailySales">Daily</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="BeforeOrderQty">Stock</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="BeforeOrderDays">Days</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="BeforeOrderDate">Date</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="AfterOrderQty">Stock</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="AfterOrderDays">Days</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="AfterOrderDate">Date</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="Price">Price</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="Discount">Discount</q-th>
              <q-th :props="props" key="Total">Total</q-th>
           </q-tr>
      </template>

      </q-table>
```